# Cassandra db running in Docker crash

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, cassandra, runtime-error

Every time I try to run Cassandra database in Docker it crash with some error message. It worked yesterday, but I guess something got corrupted, and I tried everything. Removing all volumes, containers, configurations... I tried every thing I can think of short of reinstalling Docker and reinstalling OS. I am using Ubuntu.

```
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.datastax.bdp.ioc.DseInjector.get(DseInjector.java:36)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:96)

ERROR [main] 2022-09-14 09:07:13,143  DseModule.java:102 - {}. Exiting...
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.datastax.bdp.ioc.DseInjector.get(DseInjector.java:36)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:96)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.resolveAndCheckDirectory(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1033)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySimpleConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:429)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:293)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:127)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.(DseCoreModule.java:82)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.getRequiredModules(DseModule.java:150)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:27)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

If anyone have any suggestion I would really appreciate any idea.

Comment: Please add some details on how do you launch it: `docker run ...`, `docker-compose.yaml`, kubernetes config or whatever you use. We need to know at least: exact version of your OS, which docker image you used, what arguments and mappings do you have. 

Please always provide more context.

Comment: From the error message, I'd expect two potential issues: volumes/bind-mounts issue, FS issue. Ubuntu runs in a virtual machine, right?

Answer (score 0):

From the error log outputs, I think your Docker container doesn't have permission to write to the `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog` directory.

If my guess is true, your mounted volume is using a filesystem that requires root user permissions to write. If so, you can try to change your mounted volume to a directory that only requires non-root permission, such as `/home/your_user/`.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely issue. But the problem is I don't really know how to fix it. I managed to make it work and here's how I've done it.
In docker-compose.yml there is this:
`
volumes:
            - ./data:/var/lib/cassandra
`
I changed in volume last line to `/var/lib/cassandraa`. 
Started Cassandra in Docker. Stopped it.
changed it back to `/var/lib/cassandra`. Now it works normally.

No clue why it didn't work before. No clue why it works now. But for me this step made it working.

Comment: Okay, it's good when you have made it workes. Next time if you have issues related to the configuration file, you might also want to post the file content, it may help us a bit.